# why layout going to top while soft keyboard showing in android

Tags: android, tabs

I am using `ActivityGroup`. in this i have one requirement like messaging user image and username showing on top of the layout and message editbox and send button are in bottom of the layout. while click on editbox my user details user image and name going to top and not showing on screen. if i use `WindowsoftInputMode="adjudtResize"` my tabs coming to up. if is use  `WindowsoftInputMode="adjustSpan|adjudtResize"` only tabs not coming up and again my user details going up. Is there any solution to show user details at top and tab bar should be at bottom? Please anybody help me i am getting frustrated.

Comment: any body have solution for this one?